# how can return the loss plots from function by using keras and print them as subplots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, keras, subplot

I was wondering how I could return the `hist` which stands for history in following function after training 2 models (RNN and LSTM) and print their loss functions in subplots:

```py
def train_model(model_type):
    '''
    This code is parallelised and runs on each process
    It trains a model with different layer sizes (hyperparameters)
    It saves the model and returns the score (error)
    '''
    import time

    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    import multiprocessing
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    from keras.layers import LSTM, SimpleRNN, Dense, Activation
    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping, ReduceLROnPlateau
    from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization

    print(f'Training a model: {model_type}')

    callbacks = [
        EarlyStopping(patience=10, verbose=1),
        ReduceLROnPlateau(factor=0.1, patience=3, min_lr=0.00001, verbose=1),
    ]

    model = Sequential()

    if model_type == 'rnn':
        model.add(SimpleRNN(units=1440, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))
    elif model_type == 'lstm':
        model.add(LSTM(units=1440, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1], trainX.shape[2])))

    model.add(Dense(480))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    model.fit(
        trainX,
        trainY,
        epochs=50,
        batch_size=20,
        validation_data=(testX, testY),
        verbose=1,
        callbacks=callbacks,
    )

    # predict
    Y_Train_pred = model.predict(trainX)
    Y_Test_pred = model.predict(testX)

    train_MSE = mean_squared_error(trainY, Y_Train_pred)
    test_MSE = mean_squared_error(testY, Y_Test_pred)

    # you can also return values eg. the eval score
    return {'type': model_type, 'train_MSE': train_MSE, 'test_MSE': test_MSE}
```

I tried following code:

```py
def train_model(model_type):

...
hist = model.fit(... )

# Return values eg. the eval score or plots history
    return {..., 'hist': hist}

num_workers = 2
model_types = ['rnn', 'lstm']
# guard in the main module to avoid creating subprocesses recursively.
if __name__ == "__main__":
     pool = multiprocessing.Pool(num_workers, init_worker)

    scores = pool.map(train_model, model_types  )
    for s in scores:
        #plot losses for RNN + LSTM
        f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 15))
        plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
        ax=plt.plot(s['hist'].history['loss']    ,label='Train loss')
        #ax=plt.plot(hist_RNN.history['loss']    ,label='Train loss')

        plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
        #ax=plt.plot(hist_LSTM.history['loss']    ,label='Train loss')
        ax=plt.plot(s['hist'].history['loss']    ,label='Train loss')

        plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.80, bottom=0.38, left=0.12, right=0.90, hspace=0.37, wspace=0.28)
        plt.savefig('_All_Losses_history_.png')
        plt.show()

print(scores)
```

Normally I would like to allocate independent model name like `plt.plot(hist_RNN...)` and `plt.plot(hist_LSTM...)` as I comment it so that I can call/pass them independently but since both RNN and LSTM model design are same in order to reduce the code I didn't do like that and now I'm looking for an elegant way to return those plots and print them any right place in subplot in the end!
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

```
print(history.history.keys())
plt.plot(history.history['acc'])
plt.plot(history.history['val_acc'])
```

You can asign these anothers like history.history['loss'] and play with them.

Comment: This is not the answer I'm looking for ! Please figure it out how I can return them from `def train_model(model_type):` in return `return {..., 'hist': hist}` and print plot via subplots!